# JS or jquery: get array index when using inArray

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexing

How would I get the index of a matched array value when using inArray?

I currently have this!

```
startHere = 0

var slides = new Array();
slides[0] = "home";
slides[1] = "about";
slides[2] = "working";
slides[3] = "services";
slides[4] = "who";
slides[5] = "new";
slides[6] = "contact";

if( window.location.hash != '' ) {

  anchor = window.location.hash;

  if( $.inArray(anchor, slides) ) {
    startHere = key;
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice,
K...

Comment: `$.inArray` returns the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [$.inArray() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)....

> ```
> Description: Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).
> ```

```
if( window.location.hash != '' ) {
  anchor = window.location.hash;
  var idxWhere = $.inArray(anchor, slides); // this assigns the index to a new var
  if( idxWhere > 0 ) {
    startHere = key;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response.

I had read the doc but I couldn't work out how to actually assign the index value to a new var! Could you possibly explain? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's native method `indexOf`:

```
startHere = slides.indexOf(anchor);
```

If it is not found, it will return `-1`.

Therefore, you can remove your `$.inArray` call and simply do

```
startHere = slides.indexOf(anchor);

if (startHere !== -1) {
    // code when anchor is found
}
```

to remove the jQuery method call overhead.

Documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp